# How to read csv in pyspark as different types, or map dataset into two different types

Tags: pyspark

Is there a way to map RDD as

```
covidRDD = sc.textFile("us-states.csv") \
    .map(lambda x: x.split(",")) 

#reducing states and cases by key
reducedCOVID = covidRDD.reduceByKey(lambda accum, n:accum+n)
print(reducedCOVID.take(1))
```

The dataset consists of 1 column of states and 1 column of cases. When it's created, it is read as

[[u'Washington', u'1'],...]

Thus, I want to have a column of string and a column of int. I am doing a project on RDD, so I want to avoid using dataframe.. any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Dear @tknpw,  to facilitate the other users that may want to answer this question some clarifications are looking like necessary. Let me explain some of them: First is please do elaborate abbreviations for example (RDD). Second is, please share part of dataset instead of explaining "The dataset consists of 1 column of states and 1 column of cases". That can help to reproducibility and answering your question early.

Answer (score 0):

As the dataset contains key value pair, use groupBykey and aggregate the count.

If you have a dataset like [['WH', 10], ['TX', 5], ['WH', 2], ['IL', 5], ['TX', 6]]

The code below gives this output - [('IL', 5), ('TX', 11), ('WH', 12)]

`data.groupByKey().map(lambda row: (row[0], sum(row[1]))).collect()`

can use aggregateByKey with UDF. This method requires 3 parameters start location, aggregation function within partition and aggregation function across the partitions

This code also produces the same result as above

```
def addValues(a,b):
    return a+b
data.aggregateByKey(0, addValues, addValues).collect()
```